# How to add count to Firebase data when user tap on a table row

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In my app, user select A or B in HomeViewController and then in LocationViewController, they select a place from a tableview and finally, ResultViewController tally the votes from other users.

I'm stuck at registering user selection to Firebase in LocationViewController

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if userVote == "A" {
        // add vote count by 1 to A of Location ABC in Firebase
        // register this vote to user's path too
    } else {
        // add vote count by 1 to B of Location ABC in Firebase
        // register this vote to user's path too
    }
}
```

I'm new to iOS, Swift and Firebase, I managed to get this far with the help of [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/firebase/) at AppCoda. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Firebase has [great documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/) too. In this case, you're probably look for [`transaction()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions), but it's best to simply follow the quickstart and then the programming guide end to end.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Yep, I solved it by reading the guide and using transaction() :)

Comment: Cool. Feel free to self-answer, so that others can benefit from seeing your working solution. Otherwise I'll vote to close as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution without the part where I want to also register the vote to user's ID. Not sure if it's the most efficient way, feel free to comment:

```
var businesses = [Business]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let business = businesses[indexPath.row]
    // Get the Firebase key of the selected row
    let businessId = business.businessKey
    // Get the path to the vote data
    let voteARef = ref.childByAppendingPath(businessId).childByAppendingPath("voteA")
    let voteBRef = ref.childByAppendingPath(businessId).childByAppendingPath("voteB")

    if userVote == "voteA" {

        voteARef.runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int
            if (value == nil) {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        })


    } else {

        voteBRef.runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int
            if (value == nil) {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        })
    }

    performSegueWithIdentifier("ResultSegue", sender: self)
}
```